# Flutter google_sign_in how to get grantedScopes or check hasPermissions

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I am using the Flutter google_sign_in package to sign the user in with Google (only requesting the basic scope permissions) and then in another spot in my app I need to check if the user has granted my application a certain scope (google photos access) so I can change my user interface to add a button to connect to their google photos if they have not granted access yet. The package does not seem to expose this functionality? How are other people handling this situation?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Ended up forking the repo: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/compare/main...RevRoad:flutter-plugins:add-granted-scopes

Comment: Is there any update for this? Forking the repo seems too complicated.